# Use Gitlab integrated Docker Registry in Gitlab Docker Version

Tags: docker, gitlab, docker-registry

Is it possible to run the Gitlab integrated Docker Registry on a Docker hosted Gitlab instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible you must enable it in the config file of gitlab and restart the gitlab container once